# How do I make a creature with a +0 Saving Throw bonus in Genius Inc.'s DND Monster Maker?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, tools

I'm using [Genius Inc.'s DND Monster Maker](https://thegeniusinc.com/dd-monster-maker-download/), and I can't seem to make the tool show a Saving Throw bonus of +0 in its generated stat block. I'm trying to make a monster that has a -2 to Wisdom but has proficiency in Wisdom (so net +0 bonus), but it won't show.

As a work around, I put +10 in the Wisdom Save instead, and erased the 1 after printing the stat block out.

Is there any way to make the tool show a +0 save?

Comment: Have you looked at the [instructions](https://thegeniusinc.com/dd-monster-maker-download/use-monster-making-tool/)? (I haven't used the tool myself, but step 15 does seem to explain the issue even if it makes sense to display it in your case.)

Comment: @V2Blast I didn't see those instructions (I just scrolled down to find the elusive Download button hehe), thanks! The instructions don't say anything about my case, anyway, and I've contacted the creators.

Comment: If you've found an answer, I believe it is usually good practice to give it here?

Comment: @L0neGamer I have not found an answer, and haven't received word from the creators yet.

Comment: So, is the issue that it shows a -2 or that it doesn't show a +0?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert Both. If there are no other bonuses (or penalties) to any of its Saving Throw, the generated statblock will not show a row for Saving Throw bonuses, similar to how the Monster Manual stat blocks are printed. So, if you are reading the stat block, you can see that the Wisdom, lacking the saving throw bonus line, is -2. What I wanted it to do was to show the Saving Throw bonuses row after the ability scores and say "Wis +0"

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that the tool doesn't show any score with a zero modifier, so you will just have to use the knowledge that if a saving throw or roll doesn't appear, it has a modifier of 0.

Comment: This isn't consistent with how the Monster Manual shows stat blocks. If your aim is to share it through media, this won't work.

Comment: Well @daze413 I didn't develop the tool, I am just guessing at why it might not show anything